# Error in unquie() when trying to create a animated plot in R

Tags: r, animation

I am using the code below when trying to create an animated plot which will vary of the  ReportSubmitted time, I want to see the density of Reportfee values and colour in realtion to auditor.

However I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in unique(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted)
               (Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted ==  : attempt to apply non-function
```

does anyone have any ideas?

```
saveGIF({
  for(i in unique(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted)(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted == i)){
    data <- subset( Complete_RD_ClaimData, ReportSubmitted == i )
    p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = ReportFee, y = n(), fill = Auditor, width = 1)) +
      coord_flip() +
      geom_point()+
      ggtitle(i)
    print(p)
  }
  }, movie.name = "reportfee.gif", interval = 0.1)
```

Comment: just remove the `(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted == i)` part, the loop should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong here:

```
unique(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted)(Complete_RD_ClaimData$ReportSubmitted == i)
```